# eclipse change native language to english

Tags: java, php, eclipse, ide

I'm just a beginner and installed eclipse php few days back. Today I just setup debugger in Eclipse and when I start debugging my first project I noticed that the values of variables is shown in Chinese or Japanese but not in English and the same is in Browser Output and Debug Output tabs. Please let me know how to change this to English.

Comment: You may want to add a screenshot

Comment: The "about" pop-up would help too; it could be the case that you have downloaded a Chinese/Japanese version of Eclipse by mistake.

Comment: You can check the screenshot at [link](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/9370/eclipseei.jpg)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen : If you have any idea please help me

Comment: There is a known bug in Eclipse where the Eclipse console always expects UTF-8 even with a different character set active.  I cannot locate it right now.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Thanks for this info. Is there any turnaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your support and information.

I just found the solution of this problem. I just changed some settings in `windows->preferences->php->debug`.

[Screenshot http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/6617/eclipsesolution.jpg](http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/6617/eclipsesolution.jpg)

And i don't know what are the effects of Enable CLI Debug. If anyone knows about it please let me know so that I could know its consequences.

Comment: Note: the image link is dead